# Insetting recursive lists with Magrittr piping

Tags: r, magrittr

How can I inset recursive lists in a way which allows the full modified
list to be passed further down the pipe chain?

If I have a non recursive list the `inset` and `inset2` functions work,
but what about recursive lists?

```
library(magrittr)

t1 <- list()
t1$a <- 1
t1$b <- 2

t1 %>%
  inset2("a", 5)

## $a
## [1] 5
## 
## $b
## [1] 2

t2 <- list()
t2$a <- 1
t2$b$c <- 1
t2$b$d <- 1

t2 %>% is.recursive

## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to used nested `inset2` calls.

```
t2 %>%
  inset2("b", (.) %>% extract2("b") %>% inset("d", 5))

## $a
## [1] 1
## 
## $b
## $b$c
## [1] 1
## 
## $b$d
## [1] 5
```

Here `(.) %>% extract2("b") %>% inset("d", 5))` takes `t2$b` modifies
`d` with the `inset` function and then replaces it in `t2`.